# Android Cursor skips first row in table

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I'm querying some data from sqlite database in android but from some strange reason curosor allways get even Id rows, here is my code

```
 String notificationText = null;

    this.openDataBase();

    Cursor cursor = this.myDataBase.query("message", new String[]{"id","message"}, "active=?", new String[]{"1"}, null,null, "id ASC", "1");

    if (cursor != null)
    {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        notificationText = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("message"));

        int notificationId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("active", 0);

        cursor.close();

        this.myDataBase.update("message", cv, "id=" + notificationId, null);
    }

    return notificationText;
```

So if anyone has hint what could be wrong I would appreciate it.

Comment: Could it be so happen that your `active = 1` is on the even numbered id's?

Comment: No, app comes with preloaded db and all rows are set to active = 1

Comment: how many rows do you have in your `cursor` ?

Comment: It should be only one, I did set limit to 1 in query statement

Comment: check it by `DatabaseUtils#dumpCursor`

Comment: yea, its only one row

Comment: and id is always even? it means that you have rows with only even ids?

Comment: Just as a note: `cursor.moveToFirst()` returns a `boolean` that represents if the cursor was successfully moved to the first record (being false if there are no records or any other issues preventing it). If I remember correctly, `cursor` will never be null -- it will either be empty or throw an exception. I'd replace your `if` check with: `if(cursor.moveToFirst())`